# Проблема с I/O в процессе или трубе(pipe)

Tags: c++

Задача - выполнить последовательность команд в дочерней консоли Windows и записать их вывод в родительскую консоль. 
Алгоритм программы, если я не ошибаюсь, таков:

1. Записать команду в input pipe, output которой связан с input  дочернего процесса в котором открыта консоль
2. Из output процесса записать уже результат вывода команды в input второго pipe
3. Из output второго pipe взять данные и вывести их в консоль родительского процесса

Код который должен это выполнить:

`include windows.h
include stdio.h
include strsafe.h

define BUFSIZE 4096 

HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

HANDLE g_hInputFile = NULL;

void CreateChildProcess(void);
void WriteToPipe(CHAR *);
void ReadFromPipe(void);
void ErrorExit(LPCWSTR);



int main()
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

    printf("\n->Start of parent execution.\n");

    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 

    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit(L"StdoutRd CreatePipe");

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ErrorExit(L"Stdout SetHandleInformation");

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit(L"Stdin CreatePipe");

    // Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ErrorExit(L"Stdin SetHandleInformation");

    // Create the child process. 

    CreateChildProcess();


    // Write to the pipe that is the standard input for a child process. 
    // Data is written to the pipe's buffers, so it is not necessary to wait
    // until the child process is running before writing data.

    WriteToPipe((CHAR *)"cd /");
    WriteToPipe((CHAR *)"dir");

    // Read from pipe that is the standard output for child process. 

    printf("\n->Contents of child process STDOUT:\n\n");
    ReadFromPipe();

    printf("\n->End of parent execution.\n");

    // The remaining open handles are cleaned up when this process terminates. 
    // To avoid resource leaks in a larger application, close handles explicitly. 

    return 0;
}


void CreateChildProcess()
{
    WCHAR szCmdline[] = L"cmd";
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 

    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
    // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.

    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    // Create the child process. 

    bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL,
        szCmdline,     // command line 
        NULL,          // process security attributes 
        NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
        TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
        0,             // creation flags 
        NULL,          // use parent's environment 
        NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
        &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
        &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 

     // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
    if (!bSuccess)
        ErrorExit(L"CreateProcess");
    else
    {
        // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
        // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
        // of the child process, for example. 

        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
    }
}

void WriteToPipe(CHAR *chBuf)

// Read from a file and write its contents to the pipe for the child's STDIN.
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, chBuf, sizeof(chBuf), &dwWritten, NULL);
}

void ReadFromPipe(void)

// Read output from the child process's pipe for STDOUT
// and write to the parent process's pipe for STDOUT. 
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
    WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf,
            dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
}

void ErrorExit(LPCWSTR lpszFunction)

// Format a readable error message, display a message box, 
// and exit from the application.
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPWSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL);

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCWSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen(lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPWSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        L"%s failed with error %d: %s",
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCWSTR)lpDisplayBuf, L"Error", MB_OK);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}`

Проблема заключается в том что программа выводит в родительскую консоль текст аналогичный команде "cmd", могу предположить что WriteFile() не записывает команду, но вроде как результат выполнения этой функции положительный
Не пойму в чем дело, помогите)

Comment: Алгоритм: открыть консоль, выполнить команды (вывод и так окажется в консоли).

Comment: Извиняюсь, неправильно сформулировал задачу (уже исправил пост), необходимо выполнять команды именно в дочерней консоли, а показывать их вывод в родительскую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сейчас наконец-то разобрался, вот рабочий код который делает все как мне надо:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096 
CONST HANDLE TMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL); // Мут для потоков

HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_IN_Wr = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd = NULL;
HANDLE g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr = NULL;

void CreateChildProcess(void);
void WriteToPipe(char *);
DWORD WINAPI ReadFromPipe(CONST LPVOID);
void ErrorExit(const wchar_t *);
int stmain(void);

int _tmain()
{
    stmain();
    //HANDLE shellProcess = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&stmain, TMutex, 0, NULL);
    CONST HANDLE TMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL); // Мут для потоков
    HANDLE shellThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&ReadFromPipe, TMutex, 0, NULL);
    WriteToPipe((char *)"cd / d E:/ \r\ndir\r\ncd / \r\n");
    WriteToPipe((char *)"dir \r\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
int stmain(){
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

    printf("->Start of parent execution.\n");

    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 

    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, &g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("StdoutRd CreatePipe"));

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdout SetHandleInformation"));

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 

    if (!CreatePipe(&g_hChildStd_IN_Rd, &g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin CreatePipe"));

    // Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited. 

    if (!SetHandleInformation(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        ErrorExit(TEXT("Stdin SetHandleInformation"));

    // Create the child process. 

    CreateChildProcess();


    // Write to the pipe that is the standard input for a child process. 
    // Data is written to the pipe's buffers, so it is not necessary to wait
    // until the child process is running before writing data.



    return 0;
}

void CreateChildProcess()
// Create a child process that uses the previously created pipes for STDIN and STDOUT.
{
    TCHAR szCmdline[] = TEXT("ConsoleApplication1.exe");
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;

    // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 

    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
    // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.

    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = g_hChildStd_OUT_Wr;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = g_hChildStd_IN_Rd;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    // Create the child process. 

    bSuccess = CreateProcess(NULL,
        szCmdline,     // command line 
        NULL,          // process security attributes 
        NULL,          // primary thread security attributes 
        TRUE,          // handles are inherited 
        0,             // creation flags 
        NULL,          // use parent's environment 
        NULL,          // use parent's current directory 
        &siStartInfo,  // STARTUPINFO pointer 
        &piProcInfo);  // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 

     // If an error occurs, exit the application. 
    if (!bSuccess)
        ErrorExit(TEXT("CreateProcess"));
    else
    {
        // Close handles to the child process and its primary thread.
        // Some applications might keep these handles to monitor the status
        // of the child process, for example. 

        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcInfo.hThread);
    }
}

void WriteToPipe(char *chBuf)

// Read from a file and write its contents to the pipe for the child's STDIN.
// Stop when there is no more data. 
{
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    dwRead = lstrlenA(chBuf);
    bSuccess = WriteFile(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);

    // Close the pipe handle so the child process stops reading. 

    //if (!CloseHandle(g_hChildStd_IN_Wr))
    //  ErrorExit(TEXT("StdInWr CloseHandle"));
}

DWORD WINAPI ReadFromPipe(CONST LPVOID lpParam) {
    CONST HANDLE sMutex = (CONST HANDLE)lpParam;
    WaitForSingleObject(sMutex, INFINITE);

    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
    HANDLE hParentStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    for (;;)
    {
        bSuccess = ReadFile(g_hChildStd_OUT_Rd, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0) break;

        bSuccess = WriteFile(hParentStdOut, chBuf,
            dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);
        if (!bSuccess) break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void ErrorExit(const wchar_t * lpszFunction)

// Format a readable error message, display a message box, 
// and exit from the application.
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL);

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}
```

ConsoleApplication1.exe - ексешник собраный из другого проекта, он будет дочерним процессом. Вот его код:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 4096 

int main(void)
{
    CHAR chBuf[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD dwRead, dwWritten;
    HANDLE hStdin, hStdout;
    BOOL bSuccess;

    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if (
        (hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) ||
        (hStdin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        )
        ExitProcess(1);

    // Send something to this process's stdout using printf.

    // This simple algorithm uses the existence of the pipes to control execution.
    // It relies on the pipe buffers to ensure that no data is lost.
    // Larger applications would use more advanced process control.

    system("cmd");
    for (;;)
    {
        // Read from standard input and stop on error or no data.
        bSuccess = ReadFile(hStdin, chBuf, BUFSIZE, &dwRead, NULL);

        if (!bSuccess || dwRead == 0)
            break;
        system(chBuf);
        // Write to standard output and stop on error.
        bSuccess = WriteFile(hStdout, chBuf, dwRead, &dwWritten, NULL);

        if (!bSuccess)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```